# Why am I getting double event triggers when changing the progress bar in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

It is my code, just add event listeners to a `<video>`:

```
<script >
    import {onMount} from "svelte";
    let video
    let time
    onMount(()=>{
        const events=["canplay","canplaythrough","seeked","seeking"]
        events.forEach((value)=>{
            video.addEventListener(value,()=>{
                console.log(value)})
        })
    })
</script>

<video src="/suzhou.mp4" controls
       bind:this={video}
       bind:currentTime={time}
></video>
```

When I changed the progress bar of `<video>`, it double triggers events.
[image: double triggers]

if I don't bind the currentTime, it will only trigger once, which is my expected.
[image]

Comment: Events should generally be added using `on:event` syntax in the HTML part. Here that is not much of an issue but e.g. when adding events to elements outside the components (e.g. the window), you get leaks if the handler is not removed again. `on:event` takes care of that (and one can use `<svelte:window>` to cleanly add event handlers to the window object, so they are removed on component destruction).

Comment: @H.B. the duplication seems to persist when setting the events with `on:eventname` in combination with `bind:currentTime` https://svelte.dev/repl/7272aeccc68040aca8f9c225473285b1?version=3.59.1

Comment: @Corrl: Of course it does. Were this an answer, I would have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: @H.B. I see, I missed the *Here that is not much of an issue* - sorry for bothering

Comment: Issue is not reproducible on svelte REPL. It must be related with parent component(s). https://svelte.dev/repl/3f8a26000c964e4790c5fadb05b10e92?version=3.59.2

Comment: @BulentVural it will appear when `<video>` is paused and changing the progress bar

Comment: @xunbu yes I see it now.